# Guice inject single instance into multiple objects without using @Singleton

Tags: java, guice, cyclic-dependency

I was reading the Guice documentation, and came across a section labeled [Eliminate the Cycle (Recommended)](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/CyclicDependencies#Eliminate_the_cycle_%28Recommended%29) which peaked my interest because it's exactly the issue that led me to the documentation today.

Basically, to eliminate cyclic dependencies, you "extract the Dependency Case into a separate class." *Okay, nothing new there.*

So, in the example, we have.

```
public class Store {
        private final Boss boss;
        private final CustomerLine line;
        //...

        @Inject public Store(Boss boss, CustomerLine line) {
                this.boss = boss; 
                this.line = line;
                //...
        }

        public void incomingCustomer(Customer customer) { line.add(customer); } 
}

public class Boss {
        private final Clerk clerk;
        @Inject public Boss(Clerk clerk) {
                this.clerk = clerk;
        }
}

public class Clerk {
        private final CustomerLine line;

        @Inject Clerk(CustomerLine line) {
                this.line = line;
        }

        void doSale() {
                Customer sucker = line.getNextCustomer();
                //...
        }
}
```

You have a `Store` and a `Clerk` and each need to have a reference to a single instance of `CustomerLine`. No problems with this concept, and easily doable with classic Dependency Injection:

```
CustomerLine customerLine = new CustomerLine();
Clerk clerk = new Clerk(customerLine);
Boss boss = new Boss(clerk);
Store store = new Store(boss, customerLine);
```

That's easy enough, but now, I need to do this with Guice injection. Thus, my issue is with implementing the following:

> you may want to make sure that the Store and Clerk both use
>   the same CustomerLine instance.

Yes, that is exactly what I want to do. *But how do I do that in a Guice module?*

```
public class MyModule extends AbstractModule implements Module {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        //Side Question: Do I need to do this if there if Boss.class is the implementation?
        bind(Boss.class);
        bind(CustomerLine.class).to(DefaultCustomerLine.class); //impl
    }
}
```

I create an injector with my module:

```
Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new MyModule());
```

Now, I want an instance of `Store`:

```
Store store = injector.getInstance(Store.class);
```

This will inject a new instance of `CustomerLine` and `Boss` into this instance of `Store`. `Boss`, however, gets an instance of `Clerk` which also gets injected an instance of `CustomerLine`. At this point, it would be a new instance, unique from the instance injected into `Store`.

#### Question Revisited

- How can `Store` and `Clerk` share the same instance in this sequence,
  without using `@Singleton`?

Please, let me know if more information is required, or this question isn't stated clearly enough and I will be sure to revise.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should use a [provider](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/InjectingProviders)

```
public class StoreProvider implements Provider<Store> {
  @Inject 
  private Boss boss ;

  public Store get() {
    return new Store(boss, boss.getClerk().getCustomerLine());
  }
}
```

And then bind it in your module

`bind(Store.class).toProvider(StoreProvider.class);`

Comment: That makes a lot of sense! Thanks

Comment: I think it should be 
`class StoreProvider **implements** Provider<Store>`

Comment: @BayStallion Fixed :) Thank you !

Comment: What if you need to add a constructor value?